# Custom Comment Notifications Fire on each Page Load

Tags: users, comments

I have written a custom function to notify, by email, a set of users whenever a post has a comment submitted.

The users updated vary from post to post and are defined by an array containing their emails addresses generated from their user IDs.

The code works insofar that it does send out a notification email but falls over because the emails get fired multiple times (whenever a post is loaded)

Any ideas? I'm guessing `comment_post` is the correct hook, I just have to add a conditional in the code somewhere??

**This is placed in single.php**

```
$data = array(
  'post_id'     => $post->ID,
  'title'       => get_the_title(),
  'url'         => get_the_permalink(),
  'key_holders' => $dhp->update_emails() // this contains the array of user email addresses
);

comment_notification($data);
```

**This is the code in my custom plugin**

```
add_filter( 'comment_post', 'comment_notification' ); 

function comment_notification( $data = array()) {

  if (!empty($data )) {

    $id     = get_comment( $comment_id );

    $parent = $data['post_id'];
    $plot   = $data['title'];
    $url    = $data['url'];
    $key_holders = $data['key_holders']; // this contains the array of user email addresses


    $args = array(
      'number' => '1',
      // 'post_id' => $post->ID
    );

    $comment  = get_comments( $args );

    $com_id   = $comment[0]->comment_ID;
    $author   = $comment[0]->comment_author;
    $content  = $comment[0]->comment_content;
    $time     = $comment[0]->comment_date_gmt;

    $subject  = 'Update: ' . $data['title'] . ' [' . $data['post_id'] . '/' . $com_id . ']';

    $body     = "<p>Hi</p>".
                "<p><b>" . ucwords($author) . "</b> has updated the Damson Home's Portal with the following at " . $time . "&hellip;</p>".
                wpautop($content) . "<br><p><a href=\"" . $url . "#comment-" . $com_id . "\">See the full comment here.</a></p>" .
                "<p>Warm regards</p>";

    $headers  = array(
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    );

    wp_mail( $data['key_holders'], $subject, $body, $headers );


  } else {


    echo  "<h3>Oopse!!</h3>" .
          "<p class=\"intro\">Your comment has failed, please try again.</p>" .
          "<p>Please contact us if the problem persists.</p>";

  }


}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Update (better formatted versions of @swissspidy answer)

```
add_filter( 'comment_post', 'comment_notification', 20, 3 ); 


function comment_notification( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata) {

  $postid = $commentdata['comment_post_ID']; // this is how you get the post ID

  // Stuff

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, `single.php` is the template that's loaded whenever you visit a page. And since you call `comment_notification()` there it's only logical that a notification is sent.

You should remove that code from `single.php`. Hooking into `comment_post` should be enough.

Comment: Makes sense thank you - have moved the function but for some reason I can't pick up $post->ID from within functions.php ????

Comment: If you want to get the comment's post ID, look at the documentation for the comment_post hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/. You can get the post ID via `$commentdata['comment_post_ID']`. In other words: `$post` is not something that is magically available everywhere. You have to retrieve it from somewhere.

Comment: Gotcha - I thought `global $post` was (ironically) globally accessible

This got me going...

`add_filter( 'comment_post', 'comment_notification', 20, 3 );`

`function comment_notification( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata) { ...`

`$postid  = $commentdata['comment_post_ID'];`